# Git reset and forced push

Tags: git, push, pull

Status: Learning git.

I do the following across two systems

System 1

```
git reset --hard "SHA Key"  
git push origin master # fails  
git push -f origin master # succeeds
```

System 2

```
git pull origin master
```

I get this message "Already up-to-date."

Any reason why the updates/reset from System 1 do not get reflected in System 2?

Comment: On System 2, do `git fetch` and then compare `git rev-parse origin/master` and `git rev-parse master` across both systems. Are they all the same?

Comment: on both systems do `git branch -vv` to see the tracking branch settings. It could be that on one of them, `master` tracks other branch than `origin/master`, or it does not track at all.

Comment: more details about tracking branches here: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches#Tracking-Branches

Comment: What is origin in System 1?  Is it System 2 and vice versa?  Are you pointing to a third, common location?

Comment: good point by @jszakmeister. Run `git remote -v` to find out

Comment: the origin in system 1 and system 2 is a github repository

Answer (score 5):

The reason is that you probably rewound master.  You went from this:

```
A --- B --- C --- D
```

To this:

```
A --- B --- C
```

System 2's local master branch still looks like the first picture though, and
from the Git point of view, it contains all of the history of origin master
because your local branch already contains commits A, B, and C.

I've found that the best way to explain this is that there are three views in
Git:

1) Your local branches.  These are what you normally checkout and operated on.
2) The remote branches.  These are the actual branches on the remote repository.
3) Your local snapshot of the remote branches.  These are what you find under
   `refs/remotes`.  It's a copy of the branches that were available on the
   remote repository the last time you pulled them.

When you did this:

```
git reset --hard "SHA Key"
```

You affected 1), the local master branch.

This:

```
git push -f origin master
```

Updated both 2) and 3).  What I mean is that the remote repository is updated
(`refs/heads/master` is assigned the new commit).  Also, locally,
`refs/remotes/origin/master` is brought up-to-date to match your push.

On System 2, this:

```
git pull origin master
```

Says to fetch any updates to the remote master and apply them to your local
branch.  As a result of this operation, 3) is updated too.  `refs/remotes/origin/master`
will now point to the same commit the remote server has for the master branch.
However, from Git's standpoint, you already have all of the commits on System
2's local master branch.  You just happen to have this other one, D, that
descends from A, B, and C's history.  In other words, what it now looks like is
that System 2 has an extra commit D.  Git will not rewind your branch and cause
you to lose that work--it doesn't understand that you wanted to make it gone
everywhere.  It only under stands sets (as in the mathematical kind).  You have
the revisions, so you are up-to-date.

Incidentally, this is why you see warnings everywhere about not force pushing
branches that you share with others.  Rewinding master takes team coordination,
and in a big enough group it's simply not feasible.  Someone won't realize what
happened, and the commit will be back.  Or, someone else will commit in between,
causing their push to fail, and they pull, resulting in a slightly goofy looking
history, but the commit will still return.

If D is causing a problem, and you've already shared it with the world, then
`git revert D` is a better choice.  It doesn't suffer from these problems, but
it does mean that you now have the reversion in your history.  It also means
that D is still in the set on master, there just happens to also be a -D that
undoes it.  This has some other implications, but it's probably too much to be
putting here and not directly related to your question.

Also, if System 1 is pointing at System 2 and vice versa for the remotes, then
I'm surprised Git didn't yell at you about not updating the remote branch or
working tree.  `git push` will not update a working tree on another machine, and
it's not shy about letting you know this.  If it failed to, then it's likely a
bug.

Comment: thanks for a detailed explanation. i get most of it. the chain is pretty long - A -> B -> C -> ------ R -> S. I reset from S  to C in system 1. so is revert [git revert C] the solution here? Or is it that the team would be asked to revert to "C" manually before taking this forward?

Comment: `git revert C` is definitely what you want in that case.  `git reset --hard B` would cause you to lose C through S, and I'm sure you don't want that. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You reset the HEAD of the branch to an older commit and then pushed that as the HEAD of that (master) branch.

The other repository already had that older commit so when you do git pull that is why it says already up-to-date - it already has the commit.